# Force SDKMAN! to install for Intel versions on ARM (Apple Silicon) Macs?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon, rosetta, rosetta-2, open-source

[SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) does a great job of identifying that the running Mac has an [Apple Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon) ([ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family)) chip and filtering its offerings accordingly.

For example, `sdk list java` shows only JDK product for the M1/M2/M3 chips.

Unfortunately, there are special cases where we need to install the Intel chip version of a product. The Intel versions will run on the M1/M2/M3 Macs under the [Rosetta 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)#Rosetta_2) compatibility technology in [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

Is there a way to make SDKMAN! offer Intel versions of software to install rather than ARM/Apple Silicon versions?

Comment: Have you tried asking the developers directly?